# convert highcharts to image for Persian language

Tags: javascript, image, canvas, svg, highcharts

I tried to save a Highchart as an image like this : http://jsfiddle.net/willkoehler/1p81fbzs

but when I change the text or numbers to Persian it does not work!

for example you can change the title like this:

```
title: {
        text: 'نمونه نمودار'
    },
```

and you can see that does not work. What can I do to solve it?

Comment: check this https://www.highcharts.com/docs/advanced-chart-features/internationalization. Do this helps you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can only pass [ASCII strings](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowBase64/Base64_encoding_and_decoding#The_Unicode_Problem) into window.btoa so one way around this would be to change your code to this:

```
image.src = 'data:image/svg+xml;base64,' + window.btoa(unescape(encodeURIComponent(svg)));
```

Had you checked your browser's error console you'd find an error regarding invalid strings there.

Comment: Interestingly enough, the code runs with Persian text in Firefox with [no errors](https://i.imgur.com/DcjX8WC.jpg).

Comment: @K3N Not for me it didn't until I made the change in my answer.

Comment: I think your answer is a good solution, it's just the inconsistency (on the browser part) even with the same browser (I'm using v58/win).

Comment: I'm v57/Mac, I agree it's odd that it would be different.